# Symfony2 unable to run command line tasks from doctrine-bundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, command

I'm trying to figure out why I can't see (and of course run) command line task from main doctrine-bundle for Symfony2 (2.2). When I execute

```
php app/console
```

I only see:

```
doctrine
  doctrine:database:create            Creates the configured databases
  doctrine:database:drop              Drops the configured databases
  doctrine:fixtures:load              Load data fixtures to your database.
  doctrine:generate:crud              Generates a CRUD based on a Doctrine entity
  doctrine:generate:entities          Generates entity classes and method stubs from your mapping information
  doctrine:generate:entity            Generates a new Doctrine entity inside a bundle
  doctrine:generate:form              Generates a form type class based on a Doctrine entity
  doctrine:mapping:import             Imports mapping information from an existing database
  doctrine:migrations:diff            Generate a migration by comparing your current database to your mapping information.
  doctrine:migrations:execute         Execute a single migration version up or down manually.
  doctrine:migrations:generate        Generate a blank migration class.
  doctrine:migrations:migrate         Execute a migration to a specified version or the latest available version.
  doctrine:migrations:status          View the status of a set of migrations.
  doctrine:migrations:version         Manually add and delete migration versions from the version table.
```

Why there is no tasks from

```
doctrine:schema
```

namespace?

That's my part of my AppKernel.php:

```
   $bundles = array(
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new JMS\AopBundle\JMSAopBundle(),
        new JMS\DiExtraBundle\JMSDiExtraBundle($this),
        new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),
        new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),
        new Sonata\CacheBundle\SonataCacheBundle(),
        new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
        new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),
        new Sonata\IntlBundle\SonataIntlBundle(),
        new Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle(),
        new Sonata\EasyExtendsBundle\SonataEasyExtendsBundle(),
        new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle'),
        new Sonata\SeoBundle\SonataSeoBundle(),
        new Sonata\jQueryBundle\SonatajQueryBundle(),
        new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle(),
        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
        new Genemu\Bundle\FormBundle\GenemuFormBundle(),
        new Liip\ImagineBundle\LiipImagineBundle(),
        new Knp\Bundle\GaufretteBundle\KnpGaufretteBundle(),
        new Vich\UploaderBundle\VichUploaderBundle(),
        new FOS\JsRoutingBundle\FOSJsRoutingBundle(),
        new Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle(),
        new Mopa\Bundle\BootstrapBundle\MopaBootstrapBundle(),
        new HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\HWIOAuthBundle(),

        new App\BackendBundle\AppBackendBundle(),
        new App\FrontendBundle\AppFrontendBundle(),
        new App\GeneralBundle\AppGeneralBundle(),
        new App\DemoBundle\AppDemoBundle(),
        new App\CompanyBundle\AppCompanyBundle(),
```

Is it possible that other bundle overwrites tasks from doctrine-bundle? Any hint to fix it will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried searching your codebase as is to check if doctrine schema is used by other bundles? You could also try removing bundles and rerunning app/console to see if it those options will show up.

Comment: solution was to update php to 5.4 version